# How does Virtualmin do email forwarding?

Tags: postfix, mail-forwarding, webmin, virtualmin

I'm confused: when I add forwarding to an existing email address in Virtualmin (6.08, Centos 7), it doesn't modify the /etc/postfix/virtual or any other file in /etc/ that I can tell.  When I grep for the forwarding email address, it doesn't appear *anywhere* that I can find.

How does Virtualmin make the forwarding happen, if it doesn't modify Postfix configuration?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found it.  Virtualmin modifies the /etc/aliases file, adding an entry in the format:

`username: alias@email.address,\username`

Hopefully this is helpful to someone.